# Ajax calls and a lot of MySQL delete statements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my application, I do most of server-side operations via jQuery's AJAX calls sent to one single processing page, each call specifying a different task to be performed by the processing page. I am queuing my calls so that only one call runs at a time from the calling page.
In one AJAX call, I perform 8 MySQL delete statements. The call succeeds and the processing page actually does the job, but all the next AJAX calls are not fired, unless I refresh the page and start again.
Is this a security action that the server prevents any requests from a page after a specific number of delete statements at one request?

Comment: In the browsers console is there any error messages?

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I was accessing an undefined property. Sorry, the problem was much simpler!!